# Не работает fetch запрос на Node.js/express в связке с Nginx - 404

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, config, http-status-code-404

/etc/nginx/nginx.cong

```
user nginx devx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream backend {
        server  127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  sitename.ru;
    #_;
        root         /opt/sitename/server;
    #/usr/share/nginx/html;
    index        index.html;
    #access_log   /sitename/nginx_logs/access.log;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location ~ ^/(images/||javascripts/|fonts/|data/|index.html|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
        root /opt/sitename/server;
    }
    location /clicked {proxy_pass http://backend;}
        location / {
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_buffering         on;
        }
    location /s2 { 
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
        root /opt/sitename/server/s2;
    }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

www.js (server)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('sitename:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
app.set('port', port);
//app.set('hostname', '11.111.111.11');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}
function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}
function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

app.js

```
//.....
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
//.....
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

У меня на рабочей, локальной машине все идеально на node.js работает, только без nginx. На рабочем сервере(хостинг) сайт запускается, вроде, и node.js нормально, но вот при запросе fetch на /clicked сервера не раьотает, а дает `scripts.js:1006 POST http://11.111.111.11/clicked 404 (Not Found)`

все файлы и статик, и сервер в корне - */opt/sitename/server*: /js, /css, /routes и т.д.

а вот скрипт вызова сервера здесь:

```
 button.addEventListener('click', async function (e) {
        await fetch('/clicked', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            url: `http://http://11.111.111.11:3001`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/text'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({test: 'This is just a test', prio: 1})
        })
            .then(res => res.json()).then(jsonData => resp.innerText = jsonData.message);
    });
```

пробовал везде подставлять что 11.111.111.11 айпи, что localhost, 127.0.0.1 - все одинаково.

все логично в логах. Не пойму, где я что-то пропустил. Вроде как нод работает, даже с *pm2* запустил последний раз.
лог

> 22.222.22.22 - - [05/Oct/2020:12:24:08 +0000] "POST /auth/facebook/ HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "http://22.222.222.22/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"
>
> 22.222.22.22 - - [05/Oct/2020:12:24:08 +0000] "POST /auth/facebook/ HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "http://22.222.222.22/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0" "-"

ошибки

> 2020/10/05 12:24:00 [error] 40380#0: *14 open()
> "/opt/sitename/server/clicked" failed (2: No such file or directory),
> client: 22.222.22.22, server: sitename.ru, request: "POST /clicked
> HTTP/1.1", host: "22.222.222.22", referrer: "http://22.222.122.22/"
>
> 2020/10/05 12:24:08 [error] 40380#0: *15
> "/opt/sitename/server/auth/facebook/index.html" is not found (2: No
> such file or directory), client: 22.222.22.22, server: sitename.ru,
> request: "POST /auth/facebook/ HTTP/1.1", host: "22.222.222.22",
> referrer: "http://22.222.222.22/"

а вот facebook/index.html удивило, такого вообще быть не должно, наверно, нужно страницу '/' указать при success...

Где здесь мелочь, которую я не заметил, что бы заработало?

Comment: в fetch `url: http://http://11.111.111.11:3001` - "работает нормально"?

Comment: давай упростим всё, в fetch ты должен отправлять запрос на `fetch('http://11.111.111.11/clicked'` без всякого ключа url. вопросы: в логе nginx есть этот запрос? в логе приложения есть этот запрос? что в роутах?

Comment: @nörbörnën добавил логи в вопрос...а url нужен что бы порт указать на котором node.js работает, иначе как его укажешь... запрос приходит. проблема, что route/ресурс /clicked не найден почему-то

Comment: в логах-то ответ! что не так в этой регулярке? `location ~ ^/(images/||javascripts/|fonts/|data/|index.html|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {`

Comment: `/^(images\/||javascripts\/|fonts\/|data\/)/.test('любая фигня')`

Comment: @nörbörnën эта правка regexp только поломала код, она ничего не меняет в отношении 404 и относится к статике.

Comment: **images/||javascripts/** две трубы в этом месте дают матчинг любого запроса в этот location

Comment: как дела, получилось?

Comment: @nörbörnën нет, что не пробовал - все время 404 на /route сервера... может, надо файлы ложить как-то по особому, но пробовал и в 1 папке, и раздельно серверные и статику.

Comment: если хочешь, скинь мне в телегу ssh-доступ (с возможностью sudo)(потом удалишь), я посмотрю после 5